# Python PySimpleGui and tkinter CheckBox question on text flashing

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, pysimplegui

I have a specific question on the Checkbox object in pySimplegui and Tkinter.

For reference on I'm a Windows 10 computer.
Python version 3.9.2
PySimpleGUI version 4.57.0
tkinter 8.6.9

Here are 2 coding examples

First is tKinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('My Window')
window.geometry('100x100')
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Checkbox Text', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, pady=40)
c1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Second is pySimplegui:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [[sg.Checkbox('Checkbox Text')]]
window = sg.Window("Small Checkbox", margins=(40,40), layout=layout, finalize=True) 
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

When using tKinter and clicking on the Checkbox, the text remains on the screen (non flashing).

When using pySimplegui and clicking on the Checkbox, the text turns on and off quickly (flashes).

I'm trying to eliminate that flashing when using the Checkbox in pySimplegui.   Any suggestions?

I have not been able to solve this.

Comment: That's weird. You can try to force an update on the Checkbox widget using the `sg.Checkbox()` function to avoid this flashing effect. like this `[sg.Checkbox('Checkbox Text', key='CHECKBOX', enable_events=True)]` then add an `if` statement; `if event == 'CHECKBOX':
            window['CHECKBOX'].update(window['CHECKBOX'].get())`

Answer (score 1):

You can call following statements after window finalized.

```py
check = window['Check']
check.Widget.configure(activeforeground=check.TextColor)
```

Or, upgrade your PySimpleGUI 4.57.0 from Github to PySimpleGUI >= 4.61.0.158, now it is `4.61.0.173 Unreleased`.

> 4.61.0.158
> Changed Checkbox activeforeground to be the same as the text so mouseover doesn't change color

Answer (score 0):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Checkbox('Checkbox Text', default=True)]]

window = sg.Window("Small Checkbox", margins=(40,40), layout=layout, finalize=True) 
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

You need to set the default value when establishing the checkbox, not in the window. You can also set it to False if you don't want it to show up initially.

Comment: jsteve5270 - thank you for your suggestion.

I tried adding the default=True in the layout part of the Checkbox, but I still get the flashing.  I copied that modified code you posted above and tried that - that still gave me the flashing.

Any other suggestions you are anyone else has on this?